# How to create two mutually dependent objects in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, session, transactions, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two Python classes `Note` and `Link` mapping to PostgresQL tables.  `Note` has a foreign-key reference to `Link`, while `Link` points back to the node through a piece of JSON text.  Links point to other things besides `Note`s but that doesn't matter here.

```
               Note
+------+------------------+---------+
|  ID  |       NAME       | NOTE_ID |
+------+------------------+---------+
|   1  |  Alice           |     5   |
|   2  |  Bob             |    20   |
|   3  |  Carla           |     6   |
+------+------------------+---------+

          Link
+------+--------------+
|  ID  |  CONTENT     |
+------+--------------+
| ...  |    ...       |
|   5  |  {"t":1}     |
|   6  |  {"t":3}     |
| ...  |    ...       |
|  20  |  {"t":2}     |
+------+--------------+
```

Now what I would like is that whenever I create a new `Note`

```
note = Note('Danielle')
```

it would automatically enter the row

```
(4, 'Danielle', 21)
```

into `Note`, AND enter

```
(21, '{"t":4}')
```

into `Link`.  Here's what I have tried so far: I create the `Note` object and THEN try to create the `Link` in the `@events.after_insert` event:

```
class Note(Entity):
    name = Field(Unicode)
    link = ManyToOne('Link')

    . . .

    @events.after_insert
    def create_link(self):
        """
        Create and persist the short link for this note.  Must be done
        in this after_insert event because the link table has a foreign
        key that points back to the note.  We need the note to be 
        already inserted so we can use its id.
        """
        self.link = Link.build_link_for_note(self)
        elixir.session.flush()
        print("NOTE %s GOT LINK %s" % (self, self.link))
```

In the Link class I have

```
class Link(Entity):
    . . . 
    @classmethod
    def build_link_for_note(cls, note):
        return Link(content='{"id": %d}' % note.id)
```

Both tables have autoincremented primary keys, so no worries there.  The error that I get with this code is:

```
File ".../sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1469, in flush
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError("Session is already flushing")
    InvalidRequestError: Session is already flushing
```

I'll buy that.  The `@after_insert` event gets called (I think) *after* the Note got stored to the database, which happened during the current session flush. And of course if I remove the `elixir.session.flush()` call, then of course it prints

```
NOTE <Note id:4 name:Danielle> GOT LINK <id:None content:{"t": 4}>
```

which again makes sense since I haven't been able to persist the link!

So my question is, how can I, create both a Note and a Link in a single request, so that the mutually dependent ids are available and properly recorded?

P.S. I understand that the schema here is a little unusal, and that I can solve this issue by either (1) spawning a task to create the Link asynchronously or (2) making the `Link.content` method create the link lazily.  These solutions require some concurrency attention, so I am really hoping that a simple, direct SQLAlchemy solution with one session can work.

Comment: why are you storing the foreign key from "link" to "note" as a denormalized text scheme ?  good schema design would have a "note_id" column in "link", and probably name "note.note_id" as "note.link_id" instead.  SQLAlchemy has a [documented pattern for mutually dependent foreign keys](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows).   Also, if you stick with the JSON you just need to emit an UPDATE statement directly with the Connection passed to the after_insert() event.

Comment: Very true.  But the reason is that links point to many other things besides notes.  So in the link table link ids 1-4 and 7-19 have JSON docs that refer to things other than notes.  Yes I _could_ have a separate column for all things that links can refer to (or have a kind of superclass for all those things) but this is the situation I'm working in now.

Comment: that is, [the real after_insert event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html?highlight=after_insert#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert), not the elixir version of it (emit an UPDATE statement on Connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both objects have autogenerated IDs that come from the DB *and* want to store each other's IDs, you need to save both objects first, then save one of the objects once more, with the updated ID of other object.

So I'd go with removing the `flush` call and maybe calling `save` explicitly for each of the objects involved.

Answer (score 8):

I'd advise against using Elixir's methods such as "save()" which mis-uses SQLAlchemy's API.   Here is the aforementioned approach using standard SQLAlchemy events.  Everything is achieved in one flush as well.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import event
import json

Base = declarative_base()

class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = "note"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    note_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('link.id'))

    link = relationship("Link")

    # if using __init__ here is distasteful to you,
    # feel free to use the "init" event illustrated
    # below instead
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.link = Link()

class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = "link"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = Column(String)

# using an event instead of Note.__init__
#@event.listens_for(Note, "init")
#def init(target, args, kwargs):
#    target.link = Link()

@event.listens_for(Note, "after_insert")
def after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    connection.execute(
        Link.__table__.update().\
            values(content=json.dumps({"t": target.id}))
    )

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

note = Note('Danielle')

s.add(note)
s.commit()

note = s.query(Note).first()
assert s.query(Link.content).scalar() == ('{"t": %d}' % note.id)
```

Comment: I know it's an old post - but I'm wondering - in the `after_insert` event, you execute an update on `Link.__table__` but in no where you are telling the framework which `Link` rows you want to change. Don't you need to condition on `target.note_id`? (which you should have really renamed to link_id...)
Thanks!